# Unable to retrieve property value through ValueMap - CQ 5.4

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

I accidentally encountered a situation when trying to access the property of the resource as mentioned [in this Sling Docs](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/getting-resources-and-properties-in-sling.html).

The `ValueMap` always returns `null` if the name of the property starts with a number, whereas accessing the same property via the Node API returns the value correctly.

Tried to check if the key is available in the ValueMap through `#keySet()` and `#containsKey()`. It shows all the keys, but the value corresponding to the key is null.

The following is the piece of code which i was trying to execute.

```
Iterator<Resource> resources = resourceResolver.findResources(query, "xpath");

while(resources.hasNext()) {
    Resource res = resources.next();
    ValueMap resProps = res.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
    String xyz = resProps.get("2014_xyz",String.class); // returns null

    Node node = res.adaptTo(Node.class);
    if(node.hasProperty("2014_xyz")) {
        String abc = node.getProperty("2014_xyz").getString(); //returns value
    }
}
```

Was there any restriction that the name of the property shouldn't start with a number?

I went through the [JCR repository model](http://www.day.com/specs/jcr/2.0/3_Repository_Model.html) Section 3.2.2 to check the valid names. It says valid characters as `XmlChar – InvalidChar`, where `XmlChar` is any character matching the char production at http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Char

Do they also consider the [Common Syntactic Constructs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-common-syn) mentioned in the document? And if so, why does JCR allow the use of such names as well as return the values correctly?

Or, has this got to do with the implementation of Sling? Am i missing something here?

P.S: I tested the same in CQ 5.6.1 and ValueMap appears to be working fine there. Not sure of CQ 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
resProps.get("2014_xyz", "")
```

also make sure the sling version you are referencing is the one matching cq. I"m not too sure about your specific case but i've seen similar problems if the version used for compiling didn't match the version on the server.

Comment: Why would this signature work when the other one fails? Wouldn't this just return an empty string instead of `null`? I'm not criticizing the answer, I'm just curious about how this is different. The point about different Sling versions sounds interesting.

Comment: @batavia As tom mentioned this would just return an empty string. Also am compiling it directly on the server.

Comment: it's just what we've always been using in our code. The reasoning why one might work and the other not is if the 2nd call is in a newer sling API than being used. (and/or to avoid bugs)

I'm not sure we've always been using this because of a bug or because of incomplete knowledge in our team. still it might be worth a try

Answer (score 0):

If this works in CQ 5.6.1 it looks like a bug that was fixed in the meantime, there's nothing wrong with a JCR property name starting with a number.

You might want to check the actual data type of the `2014_xyz` property, there might be an upstream conversion that makes it different from what you think.